# How to receive response from API in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working in an Angular 4 application,Trying to get data from API,In this I don't know whether I am receiving the response or not ,But I don't receive any error.

This is what I have tried...

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(`url=${this.product_Name}`)
     .subscribe(data => { this.path = data[0].Image_PATH_NAME;}, error => console.error(error));
     } 
 }
```

This is the JSON response I got from API

```
[{"Image_PATH_NAME":"assets/Images/Product_Details_Page/Show101.png"}]
```

While debugging the above lines I can't see any kind of response .I am new to Angular4 please guide me to get API response.

Comment: Do you see anything pass in the chrome's debugger network tab? And is your url correct `url=${this.product_Name}` correct?

Comment: while debugging the above line product_Name is passed but I can't see any kind of response from API,also didn't get any error

Comment: Yes ,URL is correct bcoz I can manually call the API from chrome using the same URL

Comment: What's your problem exactly then? Can you see the request go through in chrome's network debugger?

Comment: yes,I can see the request go through chrome

Comment: And so if you do a `console.log(this.path)` after assigning it, INSIDE the subcribe block, what do you get?

Comment: returns Undefined

Comment: Maybe create a small example on stackblitz then

Comment: you ,want me to create ?

Comment: Yeah you can go to https://stackblitz.com/ and create a small angular app in 2 minutes reproducing your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer for this question.

```
.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data[0]['Image_PATH_NAME']);
    });
```

console view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the old `HttpModule` in which case, you have to convert your response to JSON before use :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(`url=${this.product_Name}`)
     .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(data => { this.path = data[0].Image_PATH_NAME;}, error => console.error(error));
     } 
 }
```

Comment: It throws an error like "operty json does not exist on type object"

Comment: Can you add the list of your imports to the OP please?

Comment: import { Component,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {CartdataService} from '../../services/cartdata.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Comment: Mmm nvm then, you are using the new `HttpClientModule`, my assumption was wrong ( you should add this to the first post btw)

Answer (score 0):

if you pass in

```
this.path = data[0].Image_PATH_NAME;
```

it means your http call finished correctly. 
When you use subscribe, the first parameter is a function called when the call finished correctly, the second parameter is a function called when something went wrong.

You can also check the network section in you devtools and look for you http call to see what you got

Hope that helps